# How can I sort this hash by created_at  and  base of count in descending order

Tags: ruby, hash

I make my hash in the order listed below and I sort it in ascending order fine, but when I want to sort it in descending order I don't get the correct result.

Hash is this

```
hash_answers = {}
unless answers.blank?
  answers.each_with_index do |ans, index|
    voted_up_users = ans.votes_up_by_all_users(ans)
    voted_down_users = ans.votes_down_by_all_users(ans)

    hash_answers[ans.id] = {
        :id => ans.id,
        :count => voted_up_users.count - voted_down_users.count,
                                       :created_at => ans.created_at
    }
  end
end
```

This code above works fine when I sort it in ascending order by `created_at` and count base

```
   answers = hash_answers.sort_by { |k, v| [ v[:count] , v[:created_at] ] }
```

but how can I sort this hash in descending order by `created_at` and on base of count.

Help if anyone can
Thanks

Comment: Hashes really aren't meant for sorted data.  Are you sure you can't use an array?

Comment: If you need to reverse order that you're getting, use `Array#reverse` on your result.

Comment: 1) simplify the question as much as possible, instead of showing how you generate `hash_answers`, paste an example. 2) what means "on base of count"? 3) What's the problem with the trivial `hash_answers.sort_by { |k, v| [v[:count], -v[:created_at]] }` (or whatever criterion you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use block in sort method, in block you should provide the sort rule, in your case it might be like this:

```
temp = hash_answers.sort do |h1,h2| 
  v1 = h1.last; v2 = h2.last
  [v2[:count],v2[:created_at]] <=> [v1[:count],v1[:created_at]]
end

answer = Hash[temp]
```

Comment: perhaps `h1.value[:count]` should be `h1.last[:count]` ?

Comment: I got this error undefined method `value' for #<Array:0x000000057f5f08>

Comment: @KashifAli, you should provide real data to test

Comment: SergeBalyuk, seems to me you're right, KashifAli see the update

Comment: @megas  here is hash  "{17=>{:id=>17, :count=>1, :created_at=>Wed, 05 Sep 2012 19:02:34 UTC +00:00}, 14=>{:id=>14, :count=>2, :created_at=>Sun, 02 Sep 2012 19:20:28 UTC +00:00}, 9=>{:id=>9, :count=>0, :created_at=>Sun, 02 Sep 2012 17:09:35 UTC +00:00}, 10=>{:id=>10, :count=>2, :created_at=>Sat, 01 Sep 2012 17:09:56 UTC +00:00}, 11=>{:id=>11, :count=>0, :created_at=>Fri, 31 Aug 2012 19:13:57 UTC +00:00}, 12=>{:id=>12, :count=>2, :created_at=>Thu, 30 Aug 2012 19:19:32 UTC +00:00}}" i want to sort it in descending order by count of :count and :created_at

Comment: @KashifAli, your data is not valid, check my update, i think it might work